# Is there anything wrong with using large values for L/W for a PMOS?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, pmos, ota

Worked on a project recently for a linear circuit design course.

Professor gave us the requirements to build a 5T OTA circuit which must have a gain of 30dB, unity frequency of 200kHz, etc.

Designed the circuit in LTspice using an NMOS & PMOS model.

I ended up using L=30,000u and W=100,000u for both PMOS.

I understand for modern transistors this is quite large, and not to go off on a tangent about requirements, there wasn't any specification at all about sizing.

Anyways, he thought that was too big.

Is there anything *wrong* with having sizings this big?

Comment: So you're saying you used 30mm length??

Comment: Like I said, he didn't say anything about the size in requirements. Is there any reason to discriminate against big boy MOSFETs?

Comment: What does "a gain of 30d/B" mean? Do you mean 30 dB (note the gap between 30 and dB.

Comment: Alright I'm not going to argue with my professor over the grading. Having said that, he should specify in the requirements an upper limit for the sizing. I realize now 30,000u is 3cm lol

Comment: 100 mm width is fairly normal for a medium-power MOSFET, but gate *length* is almost *always* in the one to two digit μm. (disclaimer: I'm far more familiar with SiC than silicon, so these numbers may be off slightly). Increasing transistor width increases the current handling capability and gain; increasing the length *decreases* gain.

Comment: On the plus side, those very large transistors would have voltage ratings of several thousand volts.

Comment: @user4574 You'd need to pair the incredible channel length with an equally incredible termination. I doubt you'd get good breakdown voltage out of that.

Comment: Here's a good read https://books-library.net/files/books-library.online-08111837Ja5H2.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious issue is that this is physically bigger than a reasonably-sized op amp die, given that your channel is 30mm long and 100 mm wide. The fabrication cost and space wastage would be astronomical. Furthermore, this is unrealistic to fabricate because:

- a silicon foundry might not be able to fit that transistor into its reticle limit, so it couldn't be exposed uniformly in one pass. In fact, this single transistor is bigger than TSMC's reticle limit by more than a factor of 3.
- for manufacturing reasons, there can be upper limits on the size of a single piece of polysilicon
- you will almost certainly fail density rules in that region

There is a more immediate issue though, which is the limitations of your models. A transistor model is only useful in a certain range of sizes that it was designed for; it's very likely that your simulator's model no longer gives accurate predictions so far outside the range of "normal" MOSFET sizes. I simply wouldn't trust its results for such unusually large inputs; I'm also having trouble believing that a circuit with a 30mm*100mm PFET managed to meet a unity frequency of 200k.

With that said, it should be possible to achieve the given specs with "normal" sized FETs; 30 dB and f_ug of 200k can probably be achieved with FETs having lengths ranging between a few hundred nm to single-digit um.

Answer (score 1):

Not fundamentally, but within limits due to fabrication. I have seen 12000um as a first stage amplifier (Obviously, implemented by many fingers).

Normally one tries to use the smallest transistor possible given the specifications because, in the industry, area is proportional to $$.

However, if I got your notation right, you have used a length of 3mm and a width of 100mm. Meaning, I can actually see your transistor with my bare eye. That's not right, and I have never seen something that big before. Sounds like you brute-forced your way to meeting your specifications.

Since you are using LTspice, your model most likely accepts any length or width, but in the software we use to design, we are constrained.

You could, of course, try implementing this with many fingers, but I'd need a justification as to why such a huge transistor is needed. Normally the answer is noise and mismatch (if a diff pair), but at that kind of area I'm quite sure you are way off your optimum noise.

I think you should show us your schematic, and tell us why you cannot get a design with more reasonable sizes.

Comment: Transistors you can see with the naked eye are quite normal in power devices. It's just that usually they have a channel length of a handful of microns, and a width of many centimeters that's all curled up into a macroscopic area.

Comment: Of course, the amount of current used warrants their use. But in this context, no.

Comment: Macro transistors have been made before, like Jeri Ellsworth's single-diffused MOSFET experiment (with contacts and gate metal made by silver epoxy). Not that that's commercially relevant.